# I've taken the dog for a walk

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

(1) "I'**ve taken** the dog for a walk."

Where have you been?'

(2) "I'**ve been taking** the dog for a walk."

What is the difference between (1) and (2)? Do you say (1) when you return home after taking the dog for a walk?

Comment: (2) is often "I've been walking the dog."

Comment: To me, (1) is an announcement that that task (exercising the dog) has been done rather than an explanation of where the speaker has been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kate says, the first one emphasizes that the dog has been walked and doesn't need walking for the next few hours. The task has been completed.

The second one explains where you have been and what you've been doing. You come home and you are asked "where have you been?" "I've been walking the dog." This focuses on the activity.